# Why am i getting error when i try to assign string to istringstream object in visual studio in c++?

Tags: c++, istringstream

The following class takes a `string` line as input from the user. My aim is to store it in the `istringstream iss` and then to extract various data from the `istringstream iss` into various variables. But, when I try to initialize `iss` with `string user_input`, I am getting this error when I compile the file:

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

I think the problem is in the line `iss{user_input};` Please explain why I am getting this error.

`_input.h` header file

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include<sstream>
#include "_date.h"
#include "_time.h"

using namespace std;

//definition of class input
class _input
{
    string user_input;
    istringstream iss;

    //datamembers to be sent
    int esno,eday, emonth, eihours, eimins, eohours, eomins, emo;
    char eiap, eoap;
    string enotes;

public:
    _input();

    void get_input();
    void process_data();
};
```

`_input.cpp`  file

```cpp
#include "_input.h"

_input::_input() : user_input { "Nothing Entered" }, iss{ "" }, esno{ 0 }, eday{ 0 }, emonth{ 0 },
      eihours{ 0 }, eimins{ 0 }, eohours{ 0 }, eomins{ 0 }, emo{ 0 }, eiap{ 'n' }, eoap{ 'n' }, enotes{ "" }
{

}

void _input::get_input() // to store in iss
{
    cout << "Enter the entry : Format (Date - In Time - Out Time - Money Owed - Notes)" << endl;
    getline(cin, user_input);
    iss{user_input};  //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
}

void _input::process_data()
{
    iss >> eday >> emonth >> eihours >> eimins >> eiap >> eohours >> eomins >> eoap >> emo >> enotes;
    ++esno;
    
}
```

Comment: `x{y}` is not a valid expression in C++ syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is you cannot *initialize* an object twice. `iss` is declared and constructed as a private member of your class. It already exists when you attempt `iss{user_input}` -- that's not allowed. You don't want [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), instead you simply want to replace the content of `iss` with what is in `user_input`. For that you use [std::basic_istringstream::str](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/str). The member function `str` allows you to get or set the contents of your `istringstream`.

A short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main (void) {
    
    std::istringstream iss {};                      /* iss is declared/constructed */
    std::string s {};
    
    std::cout << "enter s: ";
    if (!getline(std::cin, s))
        return 1;
    
    iss.str(s);                                     /* replace iss content with s */
    std::cout << "iss has: "<< iss.str() << '\n';   /* check iss contains s */
    while (iss >> s)                                /* read each string in iss */
        std::cout << s << '\n';                     /* output string */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/iss
enter s: my dog has fleas
iss has: my dog has fleas
my
dog
has
fleas
```

Additional tip, have a look at [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696).

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank a lot! Beautifully explained. and great example! I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped - Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
    iss{user_input};  //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
```

It is too late (and illegal) to re/construct `iss` in `get_input`, which the syntax suggests. Instead, the stream has to be re/initialized with the new `user_input`.

```
    iss.clear();
    iss.str(user_input);
```

Comment: can you explain it more please. i dont understand the answer

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma The error line has invalid syntax (for the same reason why [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rTs6s4) does not compile). From the context, I assumed that what you wanted was to (re)set `iss` to use the new `user_input` string, which translates to a [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) + [`str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/str).